# How do I force-close all active ssh sessions that were started by a specific sshd daemon?

Tags: linux, ssh, networking, process, sshd

I have a system that runs multiple sshd daemons. Each daemon listens to a separate port.

How can I terminate all sessions started by a specific daemon without affecting other ssh sessions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the ssh port, you can simply kill all current tcp sessions that were initiated through it:

```
ss -K dport 22
```

This kills all **active** ssh sessions that were started through port 22 while leaving other ssh sessions intact. Don't forget to stop the `sshd` daemon before you kill off its sessions.

Answer (score 2):

Run this to find out which PIDs you're interested in.

```
netstat -n -eep | grep port_number
```

Run any of these commands to see the interesting processes children and terminate them:

```
ps fax
# or
pstree -p
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have the pid of the sshd,

```
pkill --parent pid
```

should send SIGTERM to all children of the sshd

maybe add `--signal kill` if you want to force-kill them